# AutoMapper - Adding Custom Formatters

Tags: c#, automapper, formatter

I am using AutoMapper 1.0 RTW and adding a couple of custom formatters:

```
    Mapper.AddFormatter<AlertTypeFormatter>(); 
    Mapper.AddFormatter<DateStringFormatter>();
```

The destination types are both string and the formatters work individually. But put them together and only the first formatter gets called. In this case the "AlertTypeFormatter".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed. For future reference, Mapper.AddFormatter actually sets up the default formatter that Automap will use. To setup type specific formatters you need to use:

```
Mapper.ForSourceType<DateTime>().AddFormatter<DateStringFormatter>();
```

Doh...

Comment: Any idea where I am going wrong with setting up the general formatters? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779068/automapper-site-wide-usage-of-ivalueformatter-for-given-types